# Find snappy compressed files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

given an AWS S3 bucket with a lot of files in it, is there a way that I can filter out only the snappy compressed files among all of these?

Answer (score 1):

Do they end with `.sz`? If they aren't marked in the filename, then one will have to inspect the start of each file, and check if they start with the [stream identifier](https://github.com/google/snappy/blob/master/framing_format.txt): 0xff 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x73 0x4e 0x61 0x50 0x70 0x59

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dan D.  This might actually work, gonna give a try.

Comment: Hi I tried working with it but this method only works with zip and gzip and for snappy I could not find a string matching that pattern anywhere in the whole file.

Comment: @ATM: But the documentation Dan D. pointed to *explicitly* states "This means that
a valid Snappy framed stream always starts with the bytes ..." So how sure are you that the files that you test are in fact 'Snappy' files, if this simple test fails? Perhaps your code works 100% but there are just no Snappy files to list.

Comment: @usr2564301: The documentation says it right but for some reason the file which I am referring to which in this case is a parquet file does not include compression type information.